# excel - rounding time to the nearest 15 minutes

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have a formula that computes the difference of several TIMES and multiplies it by 24 to get a decimal value for the total:

```
D10=(C9-D9)*24
```

I would like to do special rounding like this:

if `D9 is 1pm` and `C9 is 2:08 pm`, i would like D10 to be `1.25`

another words

```
1:53 until 2:07 would be counted as 2
2:08 until 2:22 would be 2:15
2:23 through 2:37 would be 2:30
etc
```

Does anyone know how to do such special rounding?

as doug put it:

```
i need the accrued time from 1 PM to 2:08 PM should round up to 1.25 hours whereas 1 PM to 2 PM would round down to 1 hour, in other words to the nearest quarter hour.
```

Comment: Your math isn't working.  1pm + 2:08pm = 3:08am.  1pm + 2:15pm = 3:15am.  If you subtract 1, then multiply the decimal part by 24 you end up with 3.25.

Comment: @ Lance, the OP is saying that the accrued time from 1 PM to 2:08 PM should round up to 1.25 hours whereas 1 PM to 2 PM would round down to 1 hour, in other words to the nearest quarter hour.

Comment: @lance yes doug is right

Comment: @Doug, so then he wants the _difference_ and not the _sum_?

Comment: @lance yes! the difference .sorry i will update right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the formula that will partition out the difference as you wanted:

```
=(TRUNC((D9+VALUE("00:07"))*96)-TRUNC((C9+VALUE("00:07"))*96))*VALUE("00:15")*24
```

Comment: @I__, well then I can fix it, but it means that you're not asking for the sum, you're asking for the difference.  I'll get this modified this afternoon.

Comment: @lance hey lance did you get a chance to fix it

Comment: @I__, ok done, but be warned, there are subtle bugs that sometimes affect TRUNC, so it may not always work completely perfect.  I found it worked best with the VALUE statements, so don't try and change those to their decimal equivalents.

Comment: @lance its not working, for these values: 1:08 PM 2:03 PM
 i am getting the result of 1

Comment: @I__, as you should since the difference is 0:55, and that is within 7 minutes of 1 hour as you specified.

Comment: @lance it should translate it as 2:00 - 1:15 = 0:45

Comment: @I__, ok, try again.  The hardest thing is programming is precisely understanding user requirements.

Comment: @I__, messed up, change the second D9 to a C9

Answer (score 4):

If you want the difference in time in hours, but rounded to the nearest quarter hour, then maybe all you need is something like:

```
=MROUND((C9-D9)*24,0.25)
```

Answer (score 2):

### An Excel Function Version:

As per request in comments, here's an excel function only version:

ROUND UP TO NEXT 15 MINUTE BOUNDARY:

> =TIME(HOUR(A1),15*CEILING(MINUTE(A1)/15,1),0)

- N.B. replace A1 with (t2-t1) as per the original question

ROUND TO NEAREST 15 MINUTE BOUNDARY:

> =TIME(HOUR(A1),15*ROUND(MINUTE(A1)/15,0),0)

btw: converting to string to do date manipulation should be avoided for both performance reasons, and probably also, geo reasons too. Perhaps netiher of these things are a concern for you.

---

### A VBA Version

you can do it with div and mod functions.  Not sure if you want it in vba or excel macros, but here's the approach.  Don't have excel infront of me right now, so here goes...

(do in vba if you need to reuse this a lot)

convert to fraction

d=floor(n / 0.25)

remainder=n mod 0.25

x=0.25 * round (remainder /  0.25)

answer=(d * 0.25) + x

that should be close.

... just thought of the excel bond "tick" to decimal function (what was it again).  This might be a better way to go.

coded it up in vba... basic testing only:

```
Public Function f(n As Double) As Double

    Dim d As Double, r As Double, x As Double

    d = Int(n / 0.25)
    r = n - (d * 0.25)   ' strange... couldn't use mod function with decimal?
    x = 0.25 * Round(r / 0.25)

    f = (d * 0.25) + x

End Function
```

USAGE:

(in a cell)

=f(c9-d9)

Comment: can you show me a pure excel non vba way to do this thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is another formual option

```
=(ROUND(+D9*96,0)-ROUND(+C9*96,0))/4
```

Converts each time serial to 1/4 hours (*96), rounds, adds results, and scales to hours (*4)

Comment: Typo in formula should have been - not +, corrected answer now